# In Java, how do I retrieve the data values from the xml and store them in an array?

Tags: java, xml

this is my xml file

```
<waveform>
    <Ivalue>12,13,14,15,16,17,18</Ivalue>
    <IIvalue>1,4,15,23,22,44</IIvalue>
</waveform>
<waveform>
    <Ivalue>12,13,14,15,16,17,18</Ivalue>
    <IIvalue>1,4,15,23,22,44</IIvalue>
</waveform>
```

here, I know how to retrieve the values by tags but is it possible to store these values into separate `int[]`? 
Thanks

Comment: What is your environment? Are doing this in javascript, java, C++??

Answer (score 0):

You may use **JAXB** for extracting tags like Ivalue AS STRING.

To my knowledge it is at least not easy to get it directly as int array (with JAXB)

However, it is easy to split the string using **String.split** and convert the results with 
**Integer.parse**